# Abstract Classes & Constructors

Tags: java, constructor, abstract

If I have an `abstract class` called **Employee** having a `constructor`:

```
public abstract class Employee {
    //instance fields or attributes of employee
    public Employee(String name, String extensionNumber){
       //initializing the variables
    }
```

How am I supposed to write the `constructor` of a `subclass` named **SalariedEmployee** having an additional `attribute` (not in the `super class`) ?

Answer (score 7):

You just write a constructor which is able to provide the `name` and `extensionNumber` values to the superclass constructor, and do whatever else you like.

I would personally make the `Employee` constructor `protected` as well, given that it really *is* only available to subclasses. Note that apart from that aspect, there's really no difference between the use of constructors in abstract classes and in concrete classes.

```
public abstract class Employee {
    // ...
    protected Employee(String name, String extensionNumber) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee {
    // ... (probably a field for the salary)

    public SalariedEmployee(String name, String extensionNumber, BigDecimal salary) {
        // Pass information to the superclass constructor to use as normal
        super(name, extensionNumber);
        // Use salary here
    }
}
```

Note that it's not *required* that you have parameters matching the parameters of the superclass, so long as you can provide them in the `super` call. For example:

```
public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee {
    ...

    public SalariedEmployee(Employee plainEmployee, BigDecimal salary) {
        super(plainEmployee.getName(), plainEmployee.getExtensionNumber());
        // Use salary here
    }
}
```

(You might also want to consider making `extensionNumber` an `int` instead of a `String`, as it really is likely to be a plain number - whereas full phone numbers are best stored as strings.)

Answer (score 3):

You would write the following:

```
public SalariedEmployee(String name, int extensionNumber, BigDecimal salary) {
    super(name, extensionNumber);
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

A constructor can, as it's first line, call another constructor of the same `class` using `this(args)` or a constructor of the superclass using `super(args)`. If no such call is made, then the compiler will automatically insert a call to `super()` - the no argument superclass constructor. The corollary to that is that if no such call is made, and the superclass does not have a no argument constructor, then it is a compiler error.

From [JLS §8.8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> The first statement of a constructor body may be an explicit invocation of another constructor of the same class or of the direct superclass (§8.8.7.1).
>
> ...
>
> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a constructor having the additional parameter[s] and call the super class constructor using `super` :

```
public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee {
    //instance fields or attributes of employee
    public SalariedEmployee(String name, String extensionNumber, int salary) {
       super(name,extensionNumber);
       // more logic
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the logic after the answers thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

If the subclass `SalariedEmployee` has an additional field, then you can create a constructor which accepts this parameter and then calls the parent abstract class constructor:

```
public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee {
    private String param;

    public SalariedEmployee(String name, String extensionNumber, String param) {
        super(name, extensionNumber);
        // do something with 'param', e.g.
        this.param = param;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you can do this :     this.param = param